# How can I Upload two files using two different file input in Angular Js?

Tags: angularjs

I am checking extension of files , using angular js , my html code is:

```
 <input type="file" name="file"  onchange=" angular.element(this).scope().selectFileforUpload(this.files) " required/>
 <input type="button" value="Click" ng-click="click()" />
```

and angular controller code is :

```
$scope.verifiedFileType = function (file) {

        var fileName = file.name;
        var extension = (fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf('.'), fileName.length)).toLowerCase();
        if (extension === ".pdf") {
            return true;
        }
        else {

            return false;
        }
    };


    $scope.click = function () {

        if ($scope.verifiedFileType($scope.SelectedFileForUpload)) {
            alert("Yes");
        } else {
            alert("No");
        }

    }
```

This works fine. But I want to check the extension of two files of two separete file inputs. I have tried this:

```
<input type="file" name="file"  onchange=" angular.element(this).scope().selectFileforUpload(this.files) " required/>
<input type="file" name="file2"  onchange=" angular.element(this).scope().selectFileforUpload(this.files) " required/>
<input type="button" value="Click" ng-click="click()" />


 $scope.click = function () {

        if ($scope.verifiedFileType($scope.SelectedFileForUpload[0]) && $scope.verifiedFileType($scope.SelectedFileForUpload[1])) {
            alert("Yes");
        } else {
            alert("No");
        }

    }
```

But this code doesn't run. How can I perfom this task?

Comment: Where did you define `$scope.SelectedFileForUpload`? Also, `verifiedFileType` does not need be in `$scope`

Answer (score 0):

You can try below-given directive approach to achieve this.

**Directive**

```
app.directive('ngFileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var validFormats = ['jpg'];
            element.bind('change', function () {
                var values = [];
                angular.forEach(element[0].files, function (item) {
                  var fileName = item.name;
                  console.log(fileName);
                    let ext = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase();

                    if(validFormats.indexOf(ext) == -1){
                       //Setup image upload logic here...
                    }
                });

            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

**HTML**

```
 <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <input type="file" ng-file-model="files1" multiple />
    <input type="file" ng-file-model="files" multiple />
  </body>
```

Hope this will give you boost!

Comment: How can I get the files in controller ?? So that I can pass them to sever side for uploading in database using api ? @USS

Comment: You can put API part at where I leave comment `//Setup image upload logic here...` :)

Comment: Is there any way, where I can use,  onchange=" angular.element(this).scope().selectFileforUpload(this.files) " in file input and where I need not to use directive ?? @USS

Comment: @Hoster Ok, take a ride of this official documentation for the [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive). :)